# Cordova inappbrowser plugin exc bad access

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, plugins

I've got a problem with cordova, I try to use the inAppBrowser plugin in ios 7 (Iphone 5s) and I've got the famous error EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the open function. When I try the same code on a 32bits iphone simulator it's work perfectly... Does someone have any idea ?
[image: xcode error]
Thanks

Edit: I found the solution by replacing the two files describe in this post http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/